# How to remove only some values inside of USER Path on WIndows via CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to remove only 2 values from USER Path and leave the rest. How is this possible with CMD?

I was trying:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH:C:\blp\DAPI;=%"
```

But this is looking on SYSTEM environment variable, and I want to remove it from USER environment variable.

**Edit:**

Removed /M and that is working from CMD.

Make 1.bat file with:

```
setx PATH "%PATH:C:\blp\DAPI;=%"
setx PATH "%PATH:C:\blp\DAPI\DDE;=%"
```

Click 2x and start bat file, this result:

Bat file creates 2x existing variables plus adds C:\blp\DAPI

If I go in CMD and activate this bat file from there i got the correct result.

If I make a schedule task to run this bat file upon user logon its third diff result.

What the?? I'm Linux admin and this just don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Type `setx /?` to see why.

Comment: Check up again please, i've edited.

Comment: Using setx.exe with `%PATH%` cannot be more wrong. It creates a mess by setting the user-system concatenated and expanded value as the user value. To do this right, it has to be carefully implemented via reg.exe, perhaps combined with setx.exe if we want the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message broadcasted to top-level windows. Search for existing answers that demonstrate how to do this.

Comment: Also `setx` special cases the `path`. It will ADD the path given to the system or user path. It will NOT add duplicate paths. So `setx /m path c:\users` will add C:\users to the system path the first time it is run, and tells you it already exists subsequent runs. Both `Setx`, `reg`, and `wmic` allow access to the registry key storing the path.

Comment: @eryksun I've found that solution on StackOverflow as accepted. xD

Comment: @Noodles, special-casing "PATH" must be new behavior added to setx.exe in a recent build of Windows 10. Normally I use a LTSB stable system that's a release back, which is currently 1803. It doesn't special case "PATH". I'll check 1809 and preview builds if I get the time. It would help if you state the version(s) you tested.

Comment: @eryksun That syntax was wrong this is the correct syntax https://pastebin.com/YKEmChkc Attempting it twice gives you `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s)` (and the message actually means 1 time(s)).

Answer (score 2):

This [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) code is working:

```
$path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(
    'PATH',
    'User'
)

$path = ($path.Split(';') | Where-Object { $_ -ne 'C:\blp\DAPI\DDE' }) -join ';'
$path = ($path.Split(';') | Where-Object { $_ -ne 'C:\blp\DAPI' }) -join ';'

# Set it
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
    'PATH',
    $path,
    'User'
)
```